# Problem with displaying markers on the map leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have data frame with lat, long, names and average score of some universities. I need the map to display universities whose score is in the range specified through the slider.

I write this, but I don't understand why it doesn't work. If you remove the filtering, then everything works fine.

```
ui <- fluidPage( 
  
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           
           # Copy the line below to make a slider bar 
           sliderInput("slider", label = h3("Выберите средний баллы"), min = 0, 
                       max = 800, value = c(100, 800)
    )
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
   filtered_universities = reactive({universities %>% filter( 
     aver_greV >= input$slider[1] & aver_greV <=  input$slider[2]
    )
    })
    output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
     mymap <- leaflet() %>% setView (lat = -73.985, lng = 40.748, zoom = 13) 
    
     leaflet(data = filtered_universities()) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers()
      #  mymap
    })
   
}



# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Since we don't have your data, I'm not exactly sure what's going on .  Perhaps the easiest way to start to figure it out would be to put in your server: `output$printed <- renderPrint({head(filtered_universities())})` and then in the UI, put `verbatimTextOutput("printed")`.  This will print the first few rows of your data.  Then you can see if there is, perhaps, something wrong with the filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier to answer with an extract of your data. You can do `dput(head(universities))` to post an extract.

I think your app doesn't work because you are trying to alter an existing map. To modify an existing map, you need to use `leafletProxy` in an observe or `observeEvent`, something like the following code should work : (but without an extract of your data I cannot test, so I am not sure)

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  filtered_universities = reactive({universities %>% filter( 
    aver_greV >= input$slider[1] & aver_greV <=  input$slider[2]
  )
  })
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% setView (lat = -73.985, lng = 40.748, zoom = 13) %>% addTiles()
  })
  
  observe({
    leafletProxy('mymap') %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      addMarkers(data = filtered_universities())
  })
}
```

Edit : here is a working complete minimal example with some fake data

```
universities <- data.frame(
  lat = c(0,1,0,1), 
  lng = c(0,1,1,0),
  var = c(0,1,2,3)
)

ui <- fluidPage( 
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  sliderInput("slider", label = "Slider", min = 0, max = 3, value = c(0, 3))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% setView (lat = 0, lng = 1, zoom = 5) %>% addTiles()
  })

  observe({
    df = universities %>% filter(var >= input$slider[1], var <= input$slider[2])
    leafletProxy('mymap') %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      addMarkers(data = df)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, everything worked. I did as it is written in the last example.